# Passing array to php function using ajax call does not seem to work

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I am trying to pass a js array to a php function using jquery ajax.
I don't understand why the data doesn't update on the page.

this is my code:
js:

```
$('table tr').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        storeId(id); // this function creates the id.
        var selected_lp = localStorage.getItem('reportArray');
        console.log(selected_lp);

        var query = 'selected_lp=' + selected_lp;
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../inc/updatelponadvdash.php",  //this is where i call the function. 
                data: { selected_lparr : selected_lp },
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    return true;
                }
            });

    });
```

This is what i get in the `console.log(selected_lp)`:

```
["97","96","51","48","45","50","33"]
```

This is the content of /inc/updatelponadvdash.php

```
<?php
require_once 'inc.php';

    $lploop = new User();
    $lploop->adv_lploops($_POST['selected_lparr']);
?>
```

this is the function

```
 public function adv_lploops($selected_lp){
            echo ' x '.$selected_lp. ' x '; 
}
```

The final step is to call the function to the frontend. I require the `/inc/updatelponadvdash.php` to thefrontend.

At the console I see the array updated on click.
For some reason the `$selected_lp` var in not updating in the front end.
Maybe I am not calling the function as I should?

Comment: In your ajax call you have to do something with the `data` you receive with `success`.

Comment: send another variable `test` from ajax and share `print_r($_POST)` what you get ?

Comment: the output of `print_r($_POST)` is an empty array. what can i add in the success? What can i write in order to pass the array?

Comment: Can you try `data: { selected_lparr : JSON.stringify(selected_lp) },` and then print the `$_POST` in the php file. You will need to `json_decode($_POST['selected_lparr'])`

Comment: @DavSev : did you tested with another element`test:"test"` from ajax?

Comment: @Niklesh where to place the test var? in the data:?

Comment: @AgamBanga I did what you suggested but but there was no change. still get an empty array ion the post

Comment: @DavSev Can you do one more try using `file_get_contents("php://input");`
print this in the php file & let me know the response. Use it like `$rawData = file_get_contents("php://input");
print_r($rawData);`

Comment: @AgamBanga i placed the code in the /inc/updatelponadvdash.php file and I dont get any output.

Comment: @DavSev : here `data: { selected_lparr : selected_lp , test:"test"},` then check `print_r($_POST)` ?

Comment: @Niklesh did this, added the extra var. dont see it in the `print_r` all i get is an empty array.

Comment: @DavSev, you are checking this in Network tab right?

Comment: @AgamBanga can i chat with you?

Comment: Yes sure, Ping me please

Comment: How do I ping you?

Comment: Did you get any notification for chat? else  Please open this http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142326/room-for-agam-banga-and-davsev

Answer (score 0):

Aray vaues we need to use:

```
print_r($array);
```